# Section 9 Criminal Justice Act applicable to family law?

Tags: united-kingdom, evidence, rules-of-court, criminal-procedure

Nuanced, procedural thing.

In the UK law system:

- Witness statement
- Position statement
- Statement of truth
- Statement under oath

[Criminal Procedure Rules 2020](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/759/part/16)

> Under section 9 of the Criminal Justice Act 1967, if the conditions specified in that section are met the written statement of a witness is admissible in evidence to the same extent as if that witness gave evidence in person.

I would like to accomplish something similar to Section 9, but applicable to family law, not criminal law.

---

Some [google research](https://www.hse.gov.uk/enforce/enforcementguide/investigation/witness-witness.htm#:%7E:text=14.,sign%20a%20declaration%20of%20truth.) about section 9, CJA means Criminal Justice Act:

> A s9 CJA statement is preferable because:
>
> s9 statements can, providing they have been accepted by the defence, be relied upon in court as evidence, without the witness attending court to give evidence;
>
> Section 20(2)(j) gives you the power to require a person to sign a declaration of truth. This is not the same as the perjury declaration required under s9 CJA; the latter includes an acknowledgement by the witness that they are liable to be prosecuted if they wilfully say anything that they know to be false or untrue;

Or maybe procedures from criminal law are applicable to family law by cross-pollination?

---

**EDIT / UPDATE:** Unfortunate wording

> "I would like to accomplish something similar to Section 9, but applicable to family law, not criminal law."

[I knew](https://twitter.com/marsxrobertson/status/1658782363348770816) that I get the statement of truth but a breach here is "only" contempt of the court, not perjury, that's why enthusiastic towards Section 9 and CJA.

**EDIT / UPDATE:** unfortunate context

> "gives you the power to require a person to sign a declaration of truth. This is not the same as the perjury declaration"

I understand the different and I was hoping that by quoting this snippet I will highlight this knowledge. Now I've discovered yet another inconsistency:

- Statement of truth
- Declaration of truth
- Affidavit of truth

> "be produced on durable quality A4 paper with a 3.5 cm margin"

they are destroying court bundles anyway, what's the statutory definition of durable?

Answer (score 3):

Section 9 CJA statements are for criminal proceedings, and there is no cross-pollination.

For family law, see [Rule 22.4](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2010/2955/rule/22.4?timeline=false), Family Procedure Rules 2010:

> 22.4.—(1) A witness statement is a written statement signed by a person which contains the evidence which that person would be allowed to give orally.
>
> (2) A witness statement must comply with the requirements set out in the Practice Direction 22A. (Part 17 requires a witness statement to be verified by a statement of truth.)

[Practice Direction 22A](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/family/practice_directions/pd_part_22a) is quite long and difficult for me to reproduce in full here, but of particular note is Paragraph 4.1:

> Subject to paragraph 4.2 and rules 14.2 and 29.1, the affidavit/statement must, if practicable, be in the maker's own words, it should be expressed in the first person, and the maker should –
>
> - (a) commence –
>
> > (i) in an affidavit, ‘I (full name) of (residential address) state on oath .. ’;
> >
> > (ii) in a statement, by giving his or her full name and residential address;
>
> - (b) if giving evidence in a professional, business or other occupational capacity, give the address at which he or she works in (a) above, the position held and the name of the firm or employer;
> - (c) give his or her occupation or (if none) description; and
> - (d) if it be the case that the maker is a party to the proceedings or is employed by a party to the proceedings, state that fact.

Comment: That's cool. Contempt of the court only in case of a breach. I much prefer perjury and criminal offence. Wish this difference was better explained to all the justice system users.